# pil image to numpy array conversion stops my script

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm getting an odd problem. The following code will end my script prematurely.  No exceptions thrown, just quietly resets the shell.

```
img = Image.open(file_name)
crop_box = (4, 18, 630, 464)
img = img.crop(crop_box)
arr = numpy.asarray(img, int)
```

Whereas if I change it to use a different variable like so, it runs perfectly.

```
img = Image.open(file_name)
crop_box = (4, 18, 630, 464)
img2 = img.crop(crop_box)
arr = numpy.asarray(img2, int)
```

Can anybody tell me why this is happening? (versions are: python 2.7.2, PIL 1.1.7, numpy 1.6.1)

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838446/pil-crop-and-paste-problem-cropping-doesnt-create-a-cropped-image?

Comment: What platform are you on (Windows, OSX)? Are you using IPython or Enthought or ? Could you add "print arr.size" after the numpy? (My small test script is working ok.)

Comment: You might want to try adding "img.load()" after the Image.open(). PIL does lazy loading. img.load() forces the image into memory immediately. I've had other strange PIL problems solved by img.load().

Comment: I am on windows 7 64-bit, but using the 32-bit python software. I should also have added that I see this problem with .bmp images but not with .jpg. It sounds like the lazy loading is probably the issue... I'll do the size check tomorrow

Comment: Small update: nothing after the numpy line gets executed, so there's no way to find the arr.size.  img.size looks correct for both before and after the crop.  I have had a bit of success using img.load(), though not consistently yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use img = img.crop(corp_box), the original Image object will have no reference, so Python with do garbage collection for it immediately.