# PIL cropped images return a funny PIL.Image._ImageCrop datatype

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When `cropped_image = image.crop( cords )` works properly, it returns an `Image` object that works with Scipy's `assaray`:

```
bitmap <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=1600x1200 at 0xAC9CFEC>
#SCIPY'S ASARRAY WORKS PROPERLY!
pic!! [[[ 16  18  31 255]
  [ 16  18  31 255]
  [ 16  18  31 255]
  ...,
```

But now I get a `PIL.Image._ImageCrop` object which fails.

```
bitmap <PIL.Image._ImageCrop image mode=RGBA size=1600x80 at 0x99635AC>
#SCIPY'S ASARRAY FAILS WITHOUT WARNING
pic!! <PIL.Image._ImageCrop image mode=RGBA size=1600x80 at 0x99635AC>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/dev/spectrum/final/image_handler.py", line 216, in on_left_down
    self._sample_callback()
  File "/root/dev/spectrum/final/image_handler.py", line 237, in _sample_callback
    self.__callback_function( sample )
  File "/root/dev/spectrum/final/plot_handler.py", line 117, in __init__
    self.InitUI()
  File "/root/dev/spectrum/final/plot_handler.py", line 163, in InitUI
    self.canvas_panel.draw(self.__crop_section)
  File "/root/dev/spectrum/final/plot_handler.py", line 78, in draw
    pic_avg     = pic.mean(axis=2)
ValueError: axis(=2) out of bounds
```

Why is such a problem happening?

Comment: Try using `scipy.ndimage` instead.. failing that, please post some code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a silent failure that came out of two circumstances:

First, the crop method was supplied **non-integer** numbers.

Second, [the crop operation happens to be a lazy operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838495/604511), cropping happens only when `.load()` method is called (Im unclear on this, please edit this if you know better!) .

Hence the crop operation **did not happen** and it gave no obvious signal. Giving it valid coordinates solved the problem.